# How to merge unallocated partition to linux partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I have a windows partition which was 500gb, then i installed ubuntu with a 40gb partition, now i am short of space, so i booted my ubuntu14 live cd and shrunk my windows paritition and got 88gb free unallocated space.

Now i want to merge this 88gb unallocated space to my linux parition.

What have I tried :- I tried to Move/resize this unallocated space from live cd, but it is greyed out.

What I want :- How to merge this unallocated space to my linux partition such that my 40gb linux becomes (40+88) 128gb single partition.
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:-** I needed the 88 gb so i reshrunk it to 44 gb and gave it back to windows, now the unallocated space is 44gb, and all the screenshots are taken from Gparted by live boot. So you can see the options provided.

**UPDATE 2:-** I was not able to re-allocate because of the swap on, thanks to harrymc, I got the idea what Daniel was trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because GParted does not let to resize/move the extended partition because of the swap partition that is inside it,
as it may consider the swap as mounted.

Try to right-click the swap partition and to select "Swapoff",
to be able to move the extended partition.
You might need to use "Edit → Apply All Operations" for Swapoff to have effect.

After this you can shift the unallocated space inside the extended volume, then resize the `/dev/sda5` volume to add the unallocated space.

Answer (score 4):

Because the unallocated space is in front of your Linux partition, it cannot simply be extended. Instead, you’ll have to move the whole partition first. **This is a dangerous operation, so make sure you have a backup.**

1. Change the Extended Partition’s size so it also covers the free space
2. Move the Linux partition all the way to the start of the Extended Partition. (Note: GParted apparently won’t move partitions with file systems in doesn’t understand.)
3. Then, extend the Linux partition into the free space that is now behind the partition.

You cannot move unallocated space, because it’s not “a thing”. Instead, you’ll have to move the partitions around it.

Comment: let me try it, i will accpet it later

Comment: What happens if I don't delete the swap partition ?

Comment: I am not able to move the whole extended partition

Comment: I see. I’ve tried it with GParted and updated the instructions, @penta.

Comment: what do you mean by "Extended Partition’s" here ? are u refering to /dev/sda2 ?

Comment: Yes. There can only be one Extended Partition on a disk, so there’s really no need to qualify it. ;)

Comment: I quite did not understand the 1st point, "Change the Extended Partition’s size so it also covers the free space", u meant to say that i should shrink it ?

Comment: No. I meant exactly what I said: It has to cover both its current portion of the disk as well as the unallocated space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33212/discussion-between-penta-and-daniel-b).