# How to merge two partitions in Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

***Quick question:* I just looked at the other question again and the person who asked the question is using the liveboot gparted, I just have it regular... could this be my problem? Since the one I am trying to merge to is currently in use does this cause the problem I am having? Not allowing it to modify an in-use partition... ?**

I am trying to merge two partitions on my Linux machine, but can't seem to figure out how. The closest thing that I found to my problem/answer was this question: [How to merge unallocated partition to linux partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1015557/how-to-merge-unallocated-partition-to-linux-partition)

I've tried both of the things given for the answer, but neither worked... is there anything else I can try? My partitions look nearly the same as in the question... just one other ext4 partition in the extended partition.

[image: screenshot of gparted]

The highlighted unallocated partition is the one that I am trying to merge with the last partition listed (the ext4 mounted at /home)

It would also be nice to merge the other unallocated partition (the 2.72 GB one, I took it out of my swap partition) with the partition mounted at /

Thank you to anyone who is able to help me!

Comment: Without a screenshot there's nothing we can say - we don't know how your partition are laid out.

Comment: @gronostaj I added the screenshot and some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a number of problems here:

- There's a key icon next to all of your Linux partitions (some OS themes use a padlock). It means that your partition is in use and thus locked. Most filesystems don't support operating on them live. This issue is solved by booting a live OS which runs from external media, leaving partitions unlocked. I like Ubuntu for its simplicity, Grml is also nice if you prefer something more lightweight at the cost of user-friendliness.
- Your swap partition is in the way. You can't merge non-adjacent partitions without LVM and you're not using LVM. This means you'll have to create a new swap or move it into a file on `/`.
- When merging partitions, data from all except the first one is lost. You have to make sure to move contents of your `/home` partition into `/home` on the root partition beforehand. It won't fit there though, you have 85 GB of `/home` data and just 6.5 GB free on `/`. You'll need some extra disk space.

**Before working on partitions make sure that your backups are up to date and restorable. Making a full disk image is highly recommended.** (Clonezilla is a nice Linux-based tool for this, it's available in Ubuntu for download and included in Grml's full version.)

The action plan would look something like this:

1. Make a full disk image to external disk.
2. Boot your Linux OS. Disable swap and remove it from fstab. Delete swap partition. Reboot to make sure system is functional and swap is disabled.
3. Boot from USB/DVD/whatever.

   - If you want to use unallocated space for `/`:

     1. Move `/` partition to the beginning of extended partition.
     2. Resize `/` partition to fill unallocated space.
     3. Mount `/` and `/home` partitions. Copy contents of `/home` partition to `/home` directory on `/`. Remember to preserve ownership information (eg. `rsync -a`).
     4. Unmount both partitions. Delete `/home` partition.
     5. If you don't want to use file-based swap, create the swap partition at the end of extended partition.
     6. Resize `/` again.
     7. Mount `/` partition. Remove `/home` entry from fstab.
   - If you want to leave unallocated space unallocated:

     1. Create a temporary ext4 partition in unallocated space. We'll use it to store `/home` contents before resizing `/`.
     2. Mount `/home` partition. Copy contents of `/home` partition to temporary partition. Remember to preserve ownership information (eg. `rsync -a` or `partclone` it).
     3. Unmount both partitions. Delete `/home` partition.
     4. If you don't want to use file-based swap, create the swap partition at the end of extended partition.
     5. Resize `/` partition to fill unallocated space.
     6. Mount `/` partition. Copy contents of `/home` from temporary partition to `/home` directory on `/`. Remember to preserve ownership information (eg. `rsync -a`).
     7. Delete temporary partition.
     8. Remove `/home` entry from fstab.
4. Reboot into your OS. Verify that `/home` was preserved.
5. Restore swap.